# how can I calculate a year information by week

Tags: ms-access

[image]

I want the query calculate like if week 2 for "Shalma", then "total seconds" for week 2 only will Sum in query....I want this result in query not in report, is that possible?

exp the result I want:

```
PIC                     Total Seconds           SortByWeek
```

---

```
Aida                       600                         2
Arifah                     540000                      2
Shalma                     28000                       1
Shalma                     72036900                    2
Zul                        54000000                    1
Zul                        3000                        2
Zul                        100000                      3
Zul                        283500                      4
```

it shows total by week for each name.

Comment: Build an aggregate (GROUP BY) query with filter criteria. Edit question to show desired output. Make an attempt and post the query statement.

Comment: okay I already edit, so do u understand?

Comment: The output should be possible with a simple aggregate query. Use the query design grid and click the Sigma(Totals) button on ribbon. Have you attempted? This is basic Access functionality. Review a tutorial.

Comment: yes I did it but only data with same date will Sum, not the same week

Comment: Post your attempted SQL statement in question. Need to group on the week not the date. And if there are multiple years, need to extract the year from date and include that in grouping.

Comment: SELECT union.PIC, Sum(union.[Total seconds]) AS [SumOfTotal seconds], 
    union.date_worked_smt, union.SortByWeek, day.days
    FROM [union] INNER JOIN [day] ON union.SortByWeek = day.ID
    GROUP BY union.PIC, union.date_worked_smt, union.SortByWeek, day.days
    ORDER BY union.PIC, union.SortByWeek;

Comment: that's my sql statement

Comment: if u did't mind, I can sent u the softcopy by email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the full date in grouping.

```
SELECT PIC, Sum([Total seconds]) AS [SumOfTotalSeconds], SortByWeek, Year(date_worked_smt) AS Yr, days
FROM [union] 
INNER JOIN [day] ON union.SortByWeek = day.ID 
GROUP BY PIC, Year(date_worked_smt), SortByWeek, days
ORDER BY PIC, SortByWeek;
```

Comment: You did not include days field in the sample output. Include the JOIN and day field in the SELECT and GROUP BY. The real fault was including date_worked_smt. Revised answer.